# Can't change form labels on event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have two static labels that are supposed to show the users counters that I have kept on the back end but they do not change on the form. I have tried searching for answers but I can't understand most of them.

```
        //Watchers
        private static void CDdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        { 
            CDCreated += 1; 
        }
        private static void LPdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        { 
            LPCreated += 1; 
        }
```

So the above are events where my counters go up

And below is the events I'm trying to make to create the change to the labels.

```
    private void cdCounterLbl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        cdCounterLBL.Text = CDCreated.ToString();
    }
    private void lpCounterLbl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lpCounterLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(LPCreated);
    }
```

I'm trying

```
        cdCounterLBL.TextChanged += cdCounterLbl_TextChanged;
        lpCounterLBL.TextChanged += lpCounterLbl_TextChanged;
```

I've tried the above but the labels still don't change

Comment: I can't do that cause in the filesystem event args the label is a static variable :(

Comment: Add a timer to the form that fires every 3 seconds and reads the value and sets the label.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that but that worked for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking the time to share your problem.

It seems that you misunderstood what are things like classes, variables, methods and events, and how to use them.

That said and if I understood what you want to do, this may solve your problem.

TextChanged, for label, is raised when you change the Text property by code.

It is not because you change the values of your counters that some event will be raised for the labels.

Counters and labels are two separate things, totally different and unrelated, without links, but you can link as follows:

```
private static void CDdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
  CDCreated += 1; 
  cdCounterLbl_TextChanged(this, null);
}

private static void LPdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
  LPCreated += 1;
  lpCounterLbl_TextChanged(this, null);
}

private void cdCounterLbl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  cdCounterLBL.Text = CDCreated.ToString();
}

private void lpCounterLbl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lpCounterLBL.Text = LPCreated.ToString();
}
```

So that does not work because of static methods and we have a bad design because of calling TextChanged to change the Text.

Thus here how to do.

Add a static event:

```
private static Action CountersUpdated;
```

Add in the form's Load event:

```
CountersUpdated += DoUpdateCounters;
```

And in the form's FormClosed event:

```
CountersUpdated -= DoUpdateCounters;
```

With:

```
private void DoUpdateCounters()
{ 
  cdCounterLBL.Text = CDCreated.ToString();
  lpCounterLBL.Text = LPCreated.ToString();
}
```

Now you can write:

```
private static void CDdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
  CDCreated++; 
  CallCountersUpdated();
}

private static void LPdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
  LPCreated++;
  CallCountersUpdated();
}

private static void CallCountersUpdated()
{
  if ( CountersUpdated != null ) CountersUpdated();
}
```

You can also make two events for CDCounterUpdated and LPCounterUpdated instead of one CountersUpdated.

Have a good job and a good life in C# and OOP.